# Module Object not callable from beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Just starting to build my first webscraper and I cannot figure out why my beautifulsoup module isn't able to call. Thank you for helping the beginner :(

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Import your website here
html_text = requests.get(
    'https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?searchType=personalizedSearch&from=submit&txtKeywords=python&txtLocation=').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

# Find the part of the webpage where your information is in
job = soup.find_all('li', class_='clearfix job-bx wht-shd-bx')
company_name = job.find('h3', class_='joblist-comp-name').text.replace(' ', '')
skills = job.find('span', class_='srp-skills').text.replace(' ', '')
published_date = job.find('span', class_='sim-posted').span.text

print(published_date)

print(f'''
Company name: {company_name}
Required Skills: {skills}

''')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\GamingPC\OneDrive - University of Pittsburgh\Random Work\Desktop\Python Projects\Web scraping.py", line 12, in <module>
    company_name = job.find('h3', class_ = 'joblist-comp-name').text.replace(' ', '')
  File "C:\Users\GamingPC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2253, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Comment: Your import statement is wrong.  It should be `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Thank you!! I fixed that but now im getting this error on the company_name line..AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()? I dont understand because I am following a youtube video but still getting this error. I changed it to find_all and still didn;t work :/

Comment: Update the question to have your current code, and include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Okay just updated! I have no idea why its not working. He has the same code on his program.

Answer (score 0):

```
job = soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'clearfix job-bx wht-shd-bx')
company_name = job.find('h3', class_ = 'joblist-comp-name').text.replace(' ', '')
```

`find_all()` returns a result set.  You can't call `find()` on a result set.

Answer (score 0):

As John Gordon says, you can't call `find()` on a result set, so you need to iterate over the variable `job`, something like this would work:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Import your website here
html_text = requests.get('https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?searchType=personalizedSearch&from=submit&txtKeywords=python&txtLocation=').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

#Find the part of the webpage where your information is in
job = soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'clearfix job-bx wht-shd-bx')

for item in job:
    company_name = item.find('h3', class_ = 'joblist-comp-name').text.replace(' ', '').strip()
    skills = item.find('span', class_ = 'srp-skills').text.replace(' ', '').strip()
    published_date = item.find('span', class_ = 'sim-posted').span.text

    print(published_date)

    print(f'''
    Company name: {company_name}
    Required Skills: {skills}

    ''')
```